# Why do I have to parenthesize an initializing expression that's a comma expression?

Tags: c++, initialization, comma-operator

Boiling a problem I'm having down to its essence, I can initialize a variable as an int by first executing a do-nothing lambda in a comma expression like this:

```
int main(){
  auto x = ( []{}(), 10 );          // same effect as auto x = 10;
}
```

But if I don't parenthesize the initializing expression,

```
int main(){
  auto y = []{}(), 10;              // won't compile
}
```

all of gcc, clang, and MSVC complain about trying to initialize `y` with a `void` expression.

Why do I have to parenthesize the comma expression to use it as an initializer?

Comment: _"Boiling a problem I'm having down ..."_ Sounds like you have a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you need the side effect of the lambda expression before `x` is initialized actually?

Comment: Yes. I want to execute a static_assert before computing the expression to be used in a member initialization list to initialize a class data member.

Comment: Well, `static_assert` is executed at compile time anyways. I don't think it's actually necessary to put it inside a lambda expression.

Comment: I need the static_assert to be evaluated before the initializing expression, because if the static_assert fails, the initializing expression will lead to a really horrible template instantiation error message. The purpose of the static_assert is to generate a good error message instead.

Comment: What's wrong with `auto x = []{ return 10; }(); ` ? Much clearer.

Comment: As I noted in another comment, my real goal is to use it in a member initialization list, and the real initializer is the result of a call to `std::forward`. To get the proper semantics, I'd have to give the lambda a `decltype(auto)` return type, and that would make things arguably more opaque. Not that the comma expression offers much in the way of transparency...

Answer (score 5):

In a declaration, the `,` symbol separates declarators. A simpler example:

```
int i = 2, j = 3;     // OK: declares `i` and `j`
int i = 2, 3;         // Error: `3` is not a declarator
```

In the second case, it looks ambiguous. Is the `,` separating declarators, or is the `,` part of an expression `2, 3`?

To resolve this ambiguity we can consult the language grammar (C++14 [dcl.decl]):

> *simple-declaration:*
>     *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* `;`
>     *attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> init-declarator-list* `;`
>
> *init-declarator-list:*
>     *init-declarator*
>     *init-declarator-list* `,` *init-declarator*
>
> *init-declarator:*
>     *declarator initializer<sub>opt</sub>*

The way grammars work, this means that when parsing a declaration the longest possible sequence that matches *init-declarator `,`* is considered. (This is sometimes called "maximum munch principle").   So `int i = 2,` matches *init-declarator `,`* . Then `3` fails to match `init-declarator`, so parsing fails.